# Download speed slowdowns on Google Compute Engine file server

Tags: apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, bandwidth, files

I did set up simple file server running on Apache (2.4) on one of my Compute Engine instances. The problem is the download speed for some people drops to radically low speeds. They do download they files trough browser.

I'm still on 1 year free trial. My network service tier is on default Premium.

Anything I can do to ensure high download speed for my files? I'm hosting a files for a game so they can become pretty big (0.5 GB)!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve better GCP network performance, please follow the below mentioned steps:

-Test your network using the right network performance monitoring tools like iperf, netperf, traceroute etc.

-Put your Compute Engine in the right zone. If possible put the instance in the same zone where the end user is located.

-If you need to download large files frequently, please increase your vCPU core on the instance. As 1 core = 2 gbits/sec = 250MB/sec of bandwidth.

-To transfer the data between two computers, using internal IP instead external IP will significantly increase bandwidth for the transfer.

-To get best performance, you need to fine tune window sizes according to your end user application connections

For more information, please follow the link [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml)

Comment: Well, cloud as a entire system is quite complex beast. I asked because I might have overlooked something. I'm still rather a programmer then system administrator so I could made mistakes. Anyway thanks for your replay, thanks for your time!